# Conditional Formatting In Excel for Following Scenario

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I want to highlight excel sheet cell (Column 'A') of when it does not contain the text like "Verify", "Validate" or "Evaluate" in its content if, the value in corresponding cell of Column 'B' holds the value 'Y'.

When the column 'A' can't contains the words like 'Verify', 'Validate' and 'Evaluate' if the corresponding cell in Column 'B' holds value 'N'. So just need to highlight those discrepancies if its there.

> Column 'A': Press Enter and verify this and this...
>
> Column 'B':    Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quick example. However, the second formula can be shorted in case that column B cannot be blank. See if this fits ...

[image: Example]

**EDIT**:

Here is `VBA` example as requested. You will need to save the code into current sheet (example: Sheet1 )...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim str As String
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim oCell As Object
    Dim oCellFormat As Object
    lCol = Target.Column

    If lCol = 1 Or lCol = 2 Then
       Set oCell = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    Else
        GoTo mExit
    End If
    str = UCase(oCell.Value)
    Set oCellFormat = Cells(oCell.Row, 1)
    If (str = "VERIFY" Or str = "VALIDATE" Or str = "EVALUATE") Then
        If UCase(Cells(oCell.Row, 2).Value) = "N" Then
            oCellFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red
        ElseIf UCase(Cells(oCell.Row, 2).Value) = "Y" Then
            oCellFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green
        Else
            oCellFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 'white
        End If
    Else
        oCellFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 'white
    End If
    GoTo mExit
    Exit Sub
mExit:
    Set oCell = Nothing 'free resources
    Set oCellFormat = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes..this helps but is it feasible to implement the same with the help of a macro then please let me know or guide me how to do it with the help of a macro!!

Comment: Are you trying to prevent user from entering Verify/Evaluate/Validate if column B has "N"? If so I would recommend you Data->Validation option; ... VBA for this simple task is not what I would recommend. However, if you insist I can easily write few lines of code to make it works with VBA. Now if I start writing VBA for you would you like to have focus on cell and lock user until correction is made? Or you just need coloring. As I said it all can be done (coloring; locking user until corrected value has been entered) with and without VBA. Waiting for clarification...

Comment: I just need coloring..dont want to make it protected one...but want to visit both version of code...if its possible for you do provide me both version...so that i can learn :)

Comment: But one error here that i'm getting is that i'm not able to add any other values apart from "Verify", "Validate" or "Evaluate" in Column A....so any help on this??

Comment: Oh sorry about that; I moved the line `Set oCellFormat = Cells(oCell.Row, 1)` in front of IF statement. Basically the object `oCellFormat` is not getting any value/reference unless you type one of three words `"Verify", "Validate", "Evaluate"`. Trying to set a value for `Interior.ColorIndex` would result with error as we had our object empty. Anyway, this time it should work... No matter what you type the `oCellFormat` will get its reference to specific cell in column A... Best Regards :-)

Comment: I was looking for one suggestion over here...if I want to move this section of code into the module section of VBA, then what will be the changes required? Please suggest!!